# Apache on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, installation, windows-installer

I want to install Apache server on Windows. 
The book says that i can go to official site http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi and download latest Apache version (Book year 2008, and in example showed 2.2.9v, and this example how to install on Windows, not Linux). So i go to this address, and there latest version 2.4.7, but its `.tar.bz2` and `.tar.gz` extension, and how i understand it will be difficult to install it cause its on Linux, for Windows must be .msi, but there no file with that extension, only 2.0.65 version and older. I understand that in Linux maybe appear earlier Apache version, but how it's real that in 2008 year, there was 2.2.9 version, but now in 2014 the latest .msi version 2.0.65 ?

Comment: If you want the Apache server for development purposes, I would recommend you to use XAMPP or WAMPP, it is easy to install and has the most important things inside: Apache, Mysql...

Comment: Yeah, i know it, thanks. Now I have installed OpenServer, its the same assembly, but i want to install normally all this components.

Comment: I just found this 2.2.25 version at http://apache.mirrors.pair.com//httpd/binaries/win32/ from official site, but how it real that in 2008 version was newest than now.

Answer (score 2):

Easy! Here you go:
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

You'll find the latest Apache HTTP server's there pre-built for you (Binaries).

*Edit: They are not provided in .MSI files like Apache would but you can unzip the files to C:\Apache2 and set it up manually, like a true developer!*

Comment: Thanks. But it's strange that on the official website does not have it, but on other it is.

Comment: @kxc How to install the same after downloading the Apache2.4 binaries vc15?